# Select elements of a list by comparing it to another list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose I have the following lists:

```
prod = {{"x1", {"a", "b", "c", "d"}}, {"x2", {"e", "f", 
    "g"}}, {"x3", {"h", "i", "j", "k", "l"}}, {"x4", {"m", 
    "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}}
```

and

```
sub = {{"m", "n"}, {"o", "p", "r", "q"}, {"g", "f", "e"}};
```

for each element in `sub` I want to go through `prod` and select if the element exist such that I get the following output,

```
 {{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q","r"}}}
```

I tried doing:

```
Table[Select[
  prod[[All, 2]][[i]], # == ContainsAny[Map[Sort, sub]][[i]] &], {i, 
  Length[sub]}]
```

yet it doesn't work, am I missing something?

Comment: may want to check [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A rule-based approach:

```
patt = List /@ OrderlessPatternSequence @@@ Alternatives @@ sub;
Cases[prod, {x_, y : patt} :> {x, y}]
```

> `{{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q",  "r"}}}`

And a functional approach:

```
sel = Outer[ContainsAll, Last /@ prod, sub, 1];
Pick[prod, Or @@@ sel]
```

> `{{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q",  "r"}}}`

A simpler one:

```
select[{label_, values_}] := MemberQ[sub, {OrderlessPatternSequence @@ values}]
Pick[prod, select /@ prod]
```

> `{{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}}`

You can use the same approach with `Select`:

```
Select[prod, select]
```

> `{{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}}`

Answer (score 5):

```
sortedsub = Sort /@ sub;
Select[prod, MemberQ[sortedsub, Sort[#[[2]]]] &]
```

> {{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}}

Answer (score 5):

You can also turn `prod` into an `Association` using sorted second elements as keys and then use [`Lookup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html):

```
Lookup[Sort/@sub] @ GroupBy[ Sort@*Last] @ prod
```

> {{{"x4", {"m", "n"}}}, {{"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}}, {{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}}}

Make it a function:

```
ClearAll[lookUp]

lookUp[keys_] := Lookup[Sort /@ keys] @* GroupBy[Sort@*Last]

lookUp[sub] @ prod
```

> {{{"x4", {"m", "n"}}}, {{"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}}, {{"x2", {"e", 
>       "f", "g"}}}}

Answer (score 5):

```
getMatches[prod_, sub_] := Module[{test},
  Scan[(test[Sort[#]] = True) &, sub];
  Cases[prod, {_, y_?test}]]

getMatches[prod, sub]
```

> {{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}}

Also

```
getMatches[prod_, sub_] := Module[{test},
  Scan[(test[Sort[#]] = True) &, sub];
  Select[prod, test@*Last]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p =
  {{"x1", {"a", "b", "c", "d"}}, 
   {"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, 
   {"x3", {"h","i", "j", "k", "l"}},
   {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, 
   {"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}};

s = {{"m", "n"}, {"o", "p", "r", "q"}, {"g", "f", "e"}};
```

Using `ContainsAll`

```
Pick[p, (x |-> Or @@ Map[ContainsAll[x[[2]], #]&, s]) /@ p]
```

{{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q",
"r"}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
prod = {{"x1", {"a", "b", "c", "d"}}, {"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}},
        {"x3", {"h", "i", "j", "k", "l"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}},
        {"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}};

sub = {{"m", "n"}, {"o", "p", "r", "q"}, {"g", "f", "e"}};
```

Grabbing the @C.E. pattern and using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[prod, {s : {_, patt}} :> s]

(*{{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}}*)
```

Or using `Cases` and `IntersectionQ`:

```
Cases[prod, x_ /; IntersectingQ[x[[2]], Union @@ sub]]

(*{{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prod = {{"x1", {"a", "b", "c", "d"}}, {"x2", {"e", "f", 
    "g"}}, {"x3", {"h", "i", "j", "k", "l"}}, {"x4", {"m", 
    "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q", "r"}}};

sub = {{"m", "n"}, {"o", "p", "r", "q"}, {"g", "f", "e"}};
```

---

The idea is to create a unique signature which is the product of primes by assigning a unique prime number to each character. These signatures will match, regardless of the order of the characters in a list and uniquely so.

```
tagSelect[prod_List, sub_List] := Module[
  {chars = Last /@ prod // Flatten // Union,
   primes = Prime[Range@Length@chars],
   rules = Thread[chars -> primes]
   },
  p1 = Last /@ prod /. rules // Map[Apply[Times]];
  p2 = sub /. rules // Map[Apply[Times]];
  Pick[prod, MemberQ[p2, #] & /@ p1 ]
  ]

tagSelect[prod, sub]
```

---

> {{"x2", {"e", "f", "g"}}, {"x4", {"m", "n"}}, {"x5", {"o", "p", "q",
> "r"}}}

---

On the use of `Contain*` and set-friendly functions on the page :

The OP states that `want to go through prod and select if the element exist` and it is not clear if all elements exist or these exist once only.

However, change to: `{"x2", {"e", "f", "g", "f"}}` as an entry in `prod` as a test case.